# Video does not play in android chrome when it's requested via HTTPS (Lighttpd)

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, ssl, lighttpd

I'm experiencing a very weird problem. I've two videos in H264 and V8

https://video.itusozluk.com/video/2176/1f82/21761f827364022d550cc7575a73a7dca1c112536_43.webm
https://video.itusozluk.com/video/2176/1f82/21761f827364022d550cc7575a73a7dca1c112536_18.mp4

These are playing perfectly in desktop chrome but when i try to play in android chrome they don't play.

When i try without SSL

http://video.itusozluk.com/video/2176/1f82/21761f827364022d550cc7575a73a7dca1c112536_43.webm
http://video.itusozluk.com/video/2176/1f82/21761f827364022d550cc7575a73a7dca1c112536_18.mp4

they play on android, so the problem only occurs on SSL

Here i've a screenshot from chrome inspector (on android, SSL mode)

[image]

On the other hand,

https://video.itusozluk.com

loads properly.

What could be wrong? SSL configuration? A bug?

(Version: lighttpd-1.4.18)

Answer (score -1):

Are you using a self-signed certificate in your server? I had the same problem as yours, using Android Chrome, but I solved linking the video to another server with a valid certificate.